# New Relic Email Alerting format

Tags: newrelic

I am using New Relic Lite edition which allows me to setup alerting policies and its channels. When i choose the Email channel, i don't find an option to define desired email content. I am in need of integrating these email alerts into another internal system which basically act based on these email content. 
The default format is good enough however our internal system needs a plain format with minimal details with personalized content.

Is that customization available with PRO / Enterprise account? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could always set up your own email alerts using the [webhooks feature](https://newrelic.zendesk.com/agent/tickets/121168) to obtain json formatted alerts to a URL you specify. You could then parse these alerts and send them as an email.